# Generating Sales Data by Daily, Monthly, Quarterly, & Yearly Groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to code a report that will generate 4 groups for sales data: daily, monthly, quarterly, and yearly. The problem I am running in to is that if there is no daily activity, it will not generate monthly, quarterly, or yearly. How can I get the days that have no data to generate a 0 and still calculate the other three groups? Here is the code that  I am trying to use (it does not have the year included as a group yet):

```
WITH Summary AS
(SELECT
    1 as GRP,
    'DAILY' as Label,
    O.SnapshotDateKey,
    BilledDollars = CASE WHEN SUM(O.DollarsBilled) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(O.DollarsBilled) END, 
    BilledMSF = CASE WHEN SUM(O.MsfBilled) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(O.MsfBilled) END, 
    BookedDollarsPerMSF = CASE WHEN SUM(O.MsfBilled) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (SUM(O.DollarsBilled)/SUM(O.MsfBilled)) END,
    BilledContribution = CASE WHEN SUM(O.Contribution) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(O.Contribution) END,
    BilledProfit = CASE WHEN SUM(O.Profit) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(O.Profit) END
FROM
    FactInvoiceSummary O
WHERE
    O.SnapshotDateKey = 20161230 and O.SalesRepKey = 167
GROUP BY
    O.SnapshotDateKey

UNION

SELECT
    2 as GRP,
    'MTD' as Label,
    O.SnapshotDateKey,
    BilledDollars = CASE WHEN SUM(O.MTDDollarsBilled) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (SUM(O.MTDDollarsBilled)) END, 
    BILLEDMSF = CASE WHEN SUM(O.MTDMsfBilled) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (SUM(O.MTDMsfBilled)) END, 
    BookedDollarsPerMSF = CASE WHEN SUM(O.MTDMsfBilled) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (SUM(O.MTDDollarsBilled)/SUM(O.MTDMsfBilled)) END,
    SUM(O.MTDContribution) as BilledContribution,
    SUM(O.MTDProfit) as BilledProfit
FROM
    FactInvoiceSummary O
WHERE
    O.SnapshotDateKey = 20161230 and O.SalesRepKey = 167
GROUP BY
    O.SnapshotDateKey

UNION

SELECT
    3 as GRP,
    'QTD' as Label,
    O.SnapshotDateKey,
    BilledDollars = CASE WHEN SUM(O.QTDDollarsBilled) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (SUM(O.QTDDollarsBilled)) END, 
    BILLEDMSF = CASE WHEN SUM(O.QTDMsfBilled) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (SUM(O.QTDMsfBilled)) END, 
    BookedDollarsPerMSF = CASE WHEN SUM(O.QTDMsfBilled) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (SUM(O.QTDDollarsBilled)/SUM(O.QTDMsfBilled)) END,
    SUM(O.QTDContribution) as BilledContribution,
    SUM(O.QTDProfit) as BilledProfit
FROM
    FactInvoiceSummary O
WHERE
    O.SnapshotDateKey = 20161230 and O.SalesRepKey = 167
GROUP BY
    O.SnapshotDateKey
) 

SELECT * FROM Summary
UNION ALL SELECT NULL, 0,0,0,0,0  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Summary)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please tag with db platform.

Comment: your platform is mysql & sql-server at same time?

Comment: It's a strangely common mistake for Microsoft SQL Server users to believe that they are using MySQL. I have never understood why they think the two products are the same. Maybe they don't hear anything past the first syllable?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I misread mysql as mssql - recovering from a nasty cold. We use Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing the `WHERE` clause as all parts of union query point to exact single date which may/may not contain data. Also, repeat the daily aggregation in all parts since updated `WHERE` condition will expand the number of rows. There is no need to maintain MTD, QTD, or YTD columns. Plus no need for `GROUP BY` as all columns can be aggregates with the *GRP* and *Label* constants.

Since `SnapshotDateKey` seems to captures date as a number, simply filter for appropriate range for the non-daily periods. Below is an update to CTE statement:

```
WITH Summary AS

(SELECT
    1 as GRP,
    'DAILY' as Label,
    MAX(O.SnapshotDateKey) AS MaxSnapshotDateKey,
    BilledDollars = CASE WHEN SUM(O.DollarsBilled) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(O.DollarsBilled) END, 
    BilledMSF = CASE WHEN SUM(O.MsfBilled) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(O.MsfBilled) END, 
    BookedDollarsPerMSF = CASE WHEN SUM(O.MsfBilled) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (SUM(O.DollarsBilled)/SUM(O.MsfBilled)) END,
    BilledContribution = CASE WHEN SUM(O.Contribution) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(O.Contribution) END,
    BilledProfit = CASE WHEN SUM(O.Profit) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(O.Profit) END
FROM
    FactInvoiceSummary O
WHERE
    O.SnapshotDateKey = 20161230 and O.SalesRepKey = 167

UNION

SELECT
    2 as GRP,
    'MTD' as Label,
    MAX(O.SnapshotDateKey) AS MaxSnapshotDateKey,
    BilledDollars = CASE WHEN SUM(O.DollarsBilled) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(O.DollarsBilled) END, 
    BilledMSF = CASE WHEN SUM(O.MsfBilled) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(O.MsfBilled) END, 
    BookedDollarsPerMSF = CASE WHEN SUM(O.MsfBilled) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (SUM(O.DollarsBilled)/SUM(O.MsfBilled)) END,
    BilledContribution = CASE WHEN SUM(O.Contribution) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(O.Contribution) END,
    BilledProfit = CASE WHEN SUM(O.Profit) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(O.Profit) END
FROM
    FactInvoiceSummary O
WHERE
    O.SnapshotDateKey BETWEEN 20161201 AND 20161230 and O.SalesRepKey = 167

UNION

SELECT
    3 as GRP,
    'QTD' as Label,
    MAX(O.SnapshotDateKey) AS MaxSnapshotDateKey,
    BilledDollars = CASE WHEN SUM(O.DollarsBilled) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(O.DollarsBilled) END, 
    BilledMSF = CASE WHEN SUM(O.MsfBilled) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(O.MsfBilled) END, 
    BookedDollarsPerMSF = CASE WHEN SUM(O.MsfBilled) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (SUM(O.DollarsBilled)/SUM(O.MsfBilled)) END,
    BilledContribution = CASE WHEN SUM(O.Contribution) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(O.Contribution) END,
    BilledProfit = CASE WHEN SUM(O.Profit) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(O.Profit) END
FROM
    FactInvoiceSummary O
WHERE
    O.SnapshotDateKey BETWEEN 20161001 AND 20161230 and O.SalesRepKey = 167
)
```

*Aside - Ideally, you use a datetime field which maintain date/time parts to extract day/week/month/quarter/year indicators. Also as shown above, aggregate on only **one** set of DollarsBilled, MsfBilled, Contribution, Profit columns without calculated sets for MTD, QTD, YTD.*